# Different values when I run a string through SHA1 than when I inspect it with .charCodeAt()

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, sha1

I started out with [this bizarre scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835609/differing-sha1-hashes-for-identical-values-on-the-server-and-the-client), after which somebody pointed out that I was actually getting the correct hash, but the input string's encoding was somehow wrong.

So I dug deeper.  I have this string `s` in my Node.js VM.  REPL:

```
> s
':"? O'
> s.charAt(2)
'?'
> s.charCodeAt(2)
10047
> var c = s.charAt(2)
> c.charCodeAt()
10047
```

From this alone, I would assume that there's nothing wrong with the string itself, just that my terminal was having trouble displaying it (cmd.exe on Windows XP).

However, have a look at my SHA1 function and what happens when I try to apply it:

```
function SHA1(m){
  var h = crypto.createHash('sha1');
  h.update(m);
  return h.digest('hex');
}

> SHA1(c)
'5bab61eb53176449e25c2c82f172b82cb13ffb9d'
```

Interestingly, even if I construct it manually from the codepoint, it still messes it up:

```
> SHA1(String.fromCharCode(10047)
'5bab61eb53176449e25c2c82f172b82cb13ffb9d'

> SHA1(String.fromCharCode(63))
'5bab61eb53176449e25c2c82f172b82cb13ffb9d'

This seems to happen in Chrome with Rusha, as well.
```

What's going on here?

Comment: i get a whole new `sha1` hash if i pass the `.update(String.fromCharCode(100047,'utf8')` maybe you should try it.

Comment: GeoPhoenix is right when giving string 'utf-8' is must, because default is buffer.

Comment: `.update(String.fromCharCode(100047),'utf8')` got a syntax error on first comment.

Answer (score 0):

When doing update Buffer is the [default](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_input_encoding) type. So when giving a string you must pass it explicitly.

```
>  var h = crypto.createHash('sha1');
>  h.update(String.fromCharCode(10047),'utf8').digest('hex');
'902c43163c965fb0cf4c276f9b660c97a22fb355'
>  var h = crypto.createHash('sha1');
>  h.update(String.fromCharCode(63),'utf8').digest('hex');
'5bab61eb53176449e25c2c82f172b82cb13ffb9d'
```

Comment: So then, why does h.update(String.fromCharCode(63),'utf8').digest('hex'); give the same as h.update(String.fromCharCode(63)).digest('hex'); ?

Comment: @user2958725 The coercion to buffer produces same result because of single byte payload. When it is 10047 the equivalent buffer is 3 bytes long.

Comment: Compare the buffer values : `<Buffer e2 9c bf>` vs `<Buffer 3f>`.